# Multiple values for OmniAuth.config.full_host

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth, stripe-payments

I am trying to configure Omniauth and Devise using Stripe and LinkedIn strategies on my SaaS platform.

As part of the platform each client can have their own unique domain.

I can get LinkedIn working on my client sites, but Stripe requires you list all the callback URL possibilities in their admin interface.  To work around this I have set www.myapp.com as the callback url via `OmniAuth.config.full_host` however this means I have a static callback url and then pass throught he client ID via the `state` parameter.

This works for Stripe, but then LinkedIn begins to fail as the callback domain no longer matches the originating request.

Is there a way to set `OmniAuth.config.full_host` for only certain strategies (i.e. only Stripe)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

config/initializers/omniauth.rb

```
OmniAuth.config.full_host = lambda do |env|
  if env['omniauth.strategy'].is_a?(OmniAuth::Strategies::Stripe)
    #return url for stripe
  else
    #return url for others
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option might be to override `OmniAuth::Stragies::Stripe#callback_url`.

```
#config/initializers/stripe.rb
module OmniAuth
  module Strategies
    class Stripe
      def full_host
        #return url for stripe
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The original `OmniAuth::Strategy#full_host` method will be used for the other strategies.